# Error Thrown from YII EmployeeController.php

Tags: php, yii, controller, yii2

I am using the yii2 framework and am having an issue with the EmployeeController.

When I try to edit the first 6 employees details I get thrown an error with the Employee Controller, however every account after the first 6 do not throw an error.

I get 9 errors in total.

Please see the imgur link attached to see the photo album of all 9.

Any help would be welcomed!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpDkS.jpg

**UPDATE: Added the initial error with code in order to please all.**

```
if(isset($_POST['Employee']['is_manager']) && $_POST['Employee']['is_manager']!=0){ 
                      $model_u = User::find()->where(['id'=>$model->id])->one();//print"<pre>";print_r($model_u);die('ddd');
                     if(isset($model_u->id)){
                          $p_user = UserAdmin::find()->where(['child_id'=>$model_u->id])->one();
                     }else{
                          $model_u = new User(); $p_user = new UserAdmin(); }                            
                 }else{  
                        if($model->is_manager == 1 || $model->is_manager == 2){ 
                            $model_u = User::find()->where(['id'=>$model->id])->one();//print"<pre>";print_r($model_u);die('eee');
                            $p_user = UserAdmin::find()->where(['child_id'=>$model_u->id])->one();
                        }else{
                               $model_u = new User();
                                  $p_user = new UserAdmin();           
                        }                           
                 } 
              }

    if(Yii::$app->user->can('update-employee')){ $true = true; }
        else{ if($model->user_id == Yii::$app->user->id){ $true = true;}else{$true=false;} }
```

Comment: You would prefer me to paste every single error? There is no reason to vote down because it isn't in your preferred format.

Comment: I believe someone just answered the issue thank you.

Comment: the fact that someone answer to your question don't mean you can post not well formed question ..  if you need  help you should at least help the others  to help you .. this is called  "respect " ..

Comment: It was a perfectly well formed question to receive an answer, I have added the code your response is just plain disrespectful and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In then find() below you don't retrive any User models so  in the next row when you  access to $model_u->id you  get the error "Try to get attribute of a non object"

```
$model_u = User::find()->where(['id'=>$model->id])->one();//print"<pre>";print_r($model_u);die('eee');
$p_user = UserAdmin::find()->where(['child_id'=> $model_u->id])->one();
```

'

you can try this way

```
if($model->is_manager == 1 || $model->is_manager == 2){ 
     $model_u = User::find()->where(['id'=>$model->id])->one();//print"<pre>";print_r($model_u);die('eee');
     if (isset($model_u)){
        $p_user = UserAdmin::find()->where(['child_id'=> $model_u->id])->one();
     } else {
        $model_u = new User();
        $p_user = new UserAdmin();      
     }
}
```

Comment: Perfect I will try this shortly and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Line 229 tries to access the object you created (or tried to) on line 228. But you didn't check that it returned your expected object. `var_dump()` it to double check that it was actually created, I think you'll find it didn't!